# Hive - How to efficiently Create Table As Select?

Tags: sql, hive, out-of-memory, query-optimization, hiveql

I have a hive table, `htable` that's partitioned on `foo` and `bar`. I want to create a small subset of this table for experiments, so I would think the thing to do would be

```
create table new_table like htable;

insert into new_table partition (foo, bar) select * from htable
where rand() < 0.01 and foo in (a,b)
```

This takes forever however and finally fails with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `distribute by foo, bar`:

```
    insert into new_table partition (foo, bar) select * from htable
     where rand() < 0.01 and foo in (a,b) 
    distribute by foo, bar
```

this will reduce memory consumption.

Comment: That actually finished. Thanks!