# Hive 0.11: Memory issues with querying 3T of data with 30 nodes

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Hive 0.11 cluster with 30 nodes each of which has 32GB of memory. I used this cluster to create a managed Hive table with 3T of data on HDFS. Now I am trying to insert this data into a Hive table residing on S3 with the following query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_table PARTITION (part1, part2)
SELECT * FROM hdfs_table;
```

At first I was getting "Java heap space" errors and fixed them by adding the following:

```
SET mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx8G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC;
```

After that I started getting "Task process exit with nonzero status of 137" which indicated that mapper processes were being killed by OOM killer because together they were taking up too much memory. I decided to reduce the number of mapper processes by setting the following:

```
SET mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=2
SET mapred.map.tasks=60
```

However, that didn't have any effect because of the large amount of data being processed and Hive continued creating hundreds of mappers until I set the following setting:

```
SET mapred.max.split.size=100123456789;
```

That reduced the number of mapper tasks from hundreds down to about 40. However, this started causing Java heap space errors again.

Since I created the table using the same cluster I expect the cluster to be big enough to process the table. However, all combinations of settings I've tried would bump up against memory limits.

So, how can I keep mapred.max.split.size low enough not to cause Java heap issues and also control the number of worker tasks to avoid OOM killer?

Comment: Try to add `distribute by part1, part2` as a result reducers will create less partitions and consume less memory. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39277892/2700344

Comment: My 2 cents: in theory, if the target table has exactly the same structure as the source table, you could just `ADD PARTITION (part1='xxx', part2='zzz')` in a loop, then copy all source data files to S3 with a "path" that matches the target partitions. Hive should find them automagically "inside" the partitions. But I admit I never tried that trick with object storage, only within HDFS (or between clusters)..

Comment: leftjoin, adding `distribute by part1, part2` solved the memory pressure problem. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!
Samson Scharfrichter, the reason why I transferred data from S3 to a Hive managed table was that I wanted to use dynamic partitioning of Hive managed tables to export data back to S3 in parquet but with dynamic partitions.